# vb how to search for intergers on a listview using a text box

Tags: vb.net

```
    'LViewPhotoShoot.Items.Clear()

    'LViewPhotoShoot.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending

    'For ix As Integer = 0 To LViewPhotoShoot.Items.Count - 1

    '    Dim ls As String = LViewPhotoShoot.Items(ix).Text



    '    If String.Compare(ls.Substring(0, txtBudget.Text.Length), txtBudget.Text, True) = 0 Then

    '        LViewPhotoShoot.Items(ix).Selected = True

    '        LViewPhotoShoot.Items(ix).EnsureVisible()

    '        Exit For

    '    End If

    'Next ix
```

i tried to use the above code but i dont know how to convet some of the items to integers

Comment: There are a number off different ways, I would start off with doing some Reading on Type Casting, but CInt() to start you off, better to ready up on TryParse() though.  That aside, (assuming the above code being commented is due to not knowing how to format your question) but the above code will never work anyway.  The very 1st line you're clearing the content of same list view you're attempting to search

Comment: Where do you need to convert items to integers? There are no code lines that indicate you needing to do this. All it's doing is comparing the text of each item in the listview with txtBudget.Text and marking an item as selected if matched.
The only Integer in use is ix, which is the listview index.